# Export WAR missing on STS 4.12

Tags: java, eclipse, sts

yesterday I updated my STS to the latest version 4.12.0 and today when I wanted to export my project to a .war file, this feature was not there anymore.

[image: web not included on 4.12]

Here you can see how it looked on my previous 4.8 version:
[image: WAR is there!]

I read this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/53
As I do not use maven (our project exists since 2008 and back then we did not use it) I have no way to build a war file anymore or just go back to the previous version... I don't get it, why such an easy way to build war files has been removed?

Any tipps on how I can solve this?

Comment: Sure there was maven in 2008. Maven 2 even.

Comment: Sorry, in 2008 I was starting university... :P

Comment: Perhaps this is the ideal time then to move to a maven/gradle build? I cannot really imagine a project without it. If not, did you try the `Install New Software` > `m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP` thing that was adviced on the github issue page?

Comment: I already have it installed! Thanks anyways for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading some documentation, I found that you need Eclipse for Enterprise Java Development. So just installing this plugin solved the problem:
[image: Java Enterpreise Tools]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the war plugin and not using the embedded tomcat might help.Add a servletInitializer and see if it works.